# Fail in @OneToMany relationship when merging with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
Class StationSecondaire {
//Staff
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_principal_id", nullable = false)
    public StationPrincipale getStationPrincipale() {
        return this.stationPrincipale;
    }
//Staff
}

Class StationPrincipale {
//Staff
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stationPrincipale")
    public Set<StationSecondaire> getStationSecondaires() {
        return this.stationSecondaires;
    }
//Staff
}
```

I have one list of `StationSecondaire` that I want to save in Mysql db with Hibernate.

```
// StationPrincipale sp
for (StationSecondaire ss: ssList) {
    ss.setStationPrincipale(sp);
}

ssDAO.mergeAll(ssList);  //calls merge() to the list
```

The result is: all `StationSecondaire` in db : **ok**, but I have `ssList.size()` of `sp` also (that **should be only one**).

So why do I have `ssList.size()` times of `sp` object saved in db??

Comment: Probably because you are not first persisting StationPrincipale and then passing the managed version of that StationPrincipale object to all your StationSecondaire instances. Remove the cascading from StationSecondaire.getStationPrincipale() and try to persist; see if you get a different type of error.

Comment: is it clean to remove cascading?

Comment: It is when it is applied where not needed! But I said that as a TEST, not a solution or I would have posted it as an answer. You have to solve this problem, not me. To solve it, you need to understand it first.

Comment: I have tried CascadeType.MERGE and CascadeType.PERSIST but in vain, but there is CascadeType.REFRESH, could you please explain what does the last one mean? It seems to be the solution

Comment: I said -remove- cascading. If you don't listen, I can't help you I'm afraid. Good luck figuring it out, I suggest you get a good book on JPA and actually learn this stuff.

Comment: @Gimpy thanks a lot, when i remove cascading it works fine, but i don't want to remove it :)